# Can I interrupt a journey with an NSB ordinær togbillett?

Tags: trains, tickets, norway

I am going to Norway in a few weeks, and part of my plan is to go for a hike around Finse (bad idea this time of the year, I know) while travelling from Bergen to Oslo.

Can I buy an NSB ordinær billett from Bergen to Oslo, take the first Region outbound in the morning, leave the train in Finse, go for a hike and take a later train (the latest train that day? the Region that leaves at 01:34 the next day? a train two days later, in case I find a reasonable sleeping spot in between?) and continue my journey to Oslo?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't.

Even full-price, flexible tickets (ordinær togbillett) are bound to a specific train and include a seat reservation. The flexibility is, that you can cancel and get a refund for the ticket up until the intended departure (minus a NOK 100 fee, if you cancel less that 24 hours before).

If you want to go from Bergen to Oslo and break your journey in Finse, you will have to buy separate tickets from Bergen to Finse and from Finse to Oslo, which is unfortunately quite a bit more expensive.

Comment: Is there a place to find that stated eg. on the NSB website somewhere?

Comment: @Anaphory  Not in English, but even on the Norwegian pages, it is not quite clear. It is mentioned on the page about refund conditions, that if you want to travel with a different train, than for which you originally bought your standard ticket, you have to cancel the first ticket and buy a new ticket for the other train.